# 'Unescaping' strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, escaping

Simple question. I have a program that uses AJAX to send data from an HTML form to a PHP script that creates a PDF. If a user inputs a value on the HTML form that has an apostrophe it's encoded/escaped with a backslash. For instance, 'Joe's' becomes 'Joe\s'

How can remove the backslash? I suppose I could use str_replace('\', '', $input) but I'm wondering what a broader approach to 'unescaping' a string is in PHP.

Comment: Disable MAGIC_QUOTES.

Answer (score 3):

Normal use of Ajax will not add slash characters to data.

The most likely source of them is [magic quotes](http://php.net/magic_quotes) (which are evil). [Turn them off](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php).

Comment: It would be nice to explain why they should be disabled

Comment: The magic quotes documentation (which I linked to) explains their drawbacks.

Comment: Okey, I didn't see the [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php) on the left

Answer (score 0):

Just use  `stripslashes($input);`